# How can I get the record in fields_view_get method when I into the form view from a tree view

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

*This question is my first question in stack overflow and my English is not well.I hope you can understand me.*

Goal: I want to alter my form view dynamically by the record's state.

Trouble：I can't get the record or record's active_id when I into the form view from a tree view.But I can get it if I update the form view directly.

I was troubled by this problem all day. And I find some answer, but they are not detailed enough:

1. Add the selected record's id to the context when someone clicked a record in the tree view, and you can get the id in fields_view_get method by context.But the answer doesn't tell us how to add the id to the context when I click the record in the tree view.
2. use read method:

   `@api.multi
    def read(self, fields=None, load='_classic_read'):`

   I can't understand it.

Thanks

Comment: in a tree view you cant get active_id but active_ids.

Comment: And how can I get the id of the selected record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now the only way to get the id of the record is to save
it in the context:

i was not able to find an easy solution for you but if this is urgent
you can do some thing like this:

```
 1 - define an action that opens the record in tree or kanban view without form
 2 - add a button in the tree view to force the use to open the record from there if
     he want to edit it.
 3 - that button calls a method in your model to open that record in form view
 4 - in the context add the id of that record with special key
 5 - in your fields_view_get  check if that key is in the context and change the form
     arch from there
```

action:

```xml
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" ...>
      .....
      .....
      <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
      ...
</record>
```

tree:

```xml
   <record model="ir.ui.view">
     ....
     ....
     ....
       <tree>
           ...
           ...
           <button name="open_rec" type="object" ..../>
       </tree>
    </record>
```

in model:

```py
 @api.multi
 def open_rec(self):
    # return an window action
    form_id = self.env.ref('module_name.form_xml_id').id
    context = self.env.context
    context.update({'current_rec': self.id} # change context to add rec id
    return {
        'name': _('Title'),
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'model.name',
        'view_id': form_id,
        'target': 'current',
        'context': context,
    }


@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    result = super(YourClass, self).fields_view_get(view_id, view_typ, toolbar, submenu)
    if context.get('current_rec') and view_type='form':
        # this is when you need to change the resutl
```

Hope this helps you if you find a better way post it

Comment: Yeah, it's maybe the best solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can I achieve the goal of setting the attribute of a field based on the record's value through QWEB?

Comment: If you mean the xml template of the view yes you can. Because you will have access to arch field of the view and it's xml you can alter what ever you want there

Comment: Dear Sir, it looks wonderful. But I actually tested your code..and it gave me this error ::: : localhost redirected you too many times
Please guide me.